# How to check if $n^2$ will square root evenly without square rooting $n^2$

Tags: algorithms

How can I easily check if the square root of a number is a whole number and not a decimal without computing the square rood of said number. I could square root the number (`(n^2)^1/2` or `sqrt(n^2)`) but I do not want to.

Comment: @RossMillikan no I meant sqrt(n^2). This will gives me n which is what I am looking for. Lets say n^2 = 36, that would mean n = 6, I want to know if n is an interger

Comment: I see what you mean, I fixed it

Comment: I would still write it as 'how to check if $n$ is a perfect square', because $n^2$ will _always_ 'square root evenly' - it will always have $n$ as a square root (by convention, $n$ is taken as an integer).

Comment: As a small addendum before this (likely) gets closed, I'll note that if you want to have a good 'by hand' method for checking whether a number might be a perfect square, then the best starting point is to memorize all the possible last digits (0, 1, 4, 6, 9) and even last two digits (00, 01, 04, 09; 16; 21, 24, 25, 29; 36; 41, 44, 49; 56; 61, 64, 69; 76; 81, 84, 89; 96 - you can see the pattern here) that a square can have.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I do not plan on doing this by hand, rather implement a function in python

Comment: Jebediah: if your intention is to do this for integer values (i.e., less than $2^{32}$ / $2^{64}$) then nothing you do is likely going to be faster than checking floor(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an easy way.  If you know some small factors you can check that they divide $n$ an even number of times.  For example if you find that $2^3|n$ but $2^4 \not |n$ you know that $n$ is not a square.

Comment: Don't forget computing Jacobi symbols, which will be much more effective when $n$ has few small divisors.